# Sending JSON POST to Django App

Tags: java, django, json, rest

I have a bit of Java code that attempts to send POST data over to t Django application. However, the view is simply never called. If I paste the same URL the java code hits into my browser, the Django view is called. I have no idea what I am missing, but something must be wrong with the Java write.

This is the Java function doing the write:

```
public void executeWrite(String requestUrl, JsonObject jsonObject)
{
    DataInputStream  input = null;
    try
    {
        URL                 url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConn;
        DataOutputStream printout;

        System.out.println(requestUrl);
        // URL of CGI-Bin script.
        url = new URL (requestUrl);
        // URL connection channel.
        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        // Let the run-time system (RTS) know that we want input.
        urlConn.setDoInput (true);
        // Let the RTS know that we want to do output.
        urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
        // No caching, we want the real thing.
        urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
        // Specify the content type.
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("content-type","application/json; charset=utf-8");

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(jsonObject.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now the requestURL passed into the function directly corresponds to the one for the Django view. The requestURL is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/rest/33456/create
```

This is the Django Urlconfig:

```
(r'^events/rest/(?P<key>\d+)/create', 'events.views.restCreateEvent'),
```

Finally this is the view that never gets called by the Java code

```
@csrf_exempt 
def restCreateEvent(request, key):
    #doesn't really matter what is in here it never runs
```

So, what am I doing wrong that the POST request is never received by the Django sever? I've spent about 2 hours trying to figure it out and I can't find any issues with the Java code. Clearly something is wrong though.

Comment: You should test what exactly the Java app sends and show it here to know if the problem is on Java part or Django.

Comment: How would you recommend testing it? I was trying to get Wireshark to show me the traffic, but I can't seem to make that happen. I'm on OS X. It shows me tons of other HTTP traffic, but even my working REST calls are not logged by it for some reason.

Comment: Do you see request coming in on development server? Check you don't multiple definition of same function in the view.

Comment: @Jon You can use netcat to listen to port 8000 and stop due django server. Packet is printed to console. In Linux syntax is nc -l -p 8000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your view is [csrf exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-protection-should-be-disabled-for-just-a-few-views) since you are not sending the appropriate CSRF token from the Java request.

Comment: I made that change, but the error still persists. It certainly is a step in the right direction though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the crsf thing was actually the issue. Once I added that I changed the Java code slightly and it worked. I am still not sure what the subtle Java error was, here is the working Java code.

```
public void executeWrite(String requestUrl, JsonObject jsonObject)
{
    InputStreamReader  input = null;
    try
    {
        URL                 url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConn;
        DataOutputStream printout;

        System.out.println(requestUrl);
        // URL of CGI-Bin script.
        url = new URL (requestUrl);
        // URL connection channel.
        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        // Let the run-time system (RTS) know that we want input.
        urlConn.setDoInput (true);
        // Let the RTS know that we want to do output.
        urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
        // No caching, we want the real thing.
        urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
        // Specify the content type.
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("content-type","application/json; charset=utf-8");

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(jsonObject.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        input = new InputStreamReader (urlConn.getInputStream ());
        String response = UserInterface.read(new BufferedReader(input));

        if(response.length() > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Response:" + response);
        }

        input.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I remember the URL need change to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/rest/33456/create/" when use "POST" type.